# what is wrong with this foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I created two tables which are `customer_tbl` and `pick_up_tbl` and im trying to create the third table that its field with reference from the first table, but end up with this:

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

```
CREATE TABLE pic_rooster_tbl (
    pic_ros_id int not null,
    pic_id int not null,
    c_id int not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    dat date,
    PRIMARY KEY (pic_ros_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pic_id) REFERENCES Pickup_tbl (pic_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES customer_tbl (c_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dat) REFERENCES Pickup_tbl (dat)
);
```

Comment: You would need to show us the `create table` statement for `customer_tbl` and `pickup_tbl`.

Comment: Why are you using a `date` column as a forign key? You already have a foreign key to the ID in that table.

Comment: The problem is probably that you don't have an index on `Pickup_tbl.dat`.

Comment: If the date is already in Pickup_tbl, you shouldn't duplicate it here.

Comment: You can get more detailed information on the cause of the foreign key error by running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and looking for the section "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR"